# Apache 404 Error When 'index' is in the Path

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http, shared-hosting

I have a long standing problem with mod_rewrite and 1and1 shared hosting (hope that being shared hosting does't get this migrated to 'sharedserverfault'). Everything about the rewrite rules work fine - except when 'index' is in the path. Then I get an Apache 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Pretty standard so far, works fine on most server. On 1and1's server I get a 404 error if index is the top 'directory'. Anything starting with 'http://example.com/index' will give a 404.

- http://example.com/index
- http://example.com/index/action
- http://example.com/index/what/ever.anything

If I copy index.php to bootstrap.php and change the .htaccess file to point there and *delete* index.php, it will work.

However, that makes it a pain to update the server - any ideas what apache settings are causing this? Obviously I can't change the main configuration file, but I can override settings with the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/blog/zend-framework/zend-framework-1and1-index-controller-404s-solution/):

> After some digging around, the solution is to disable something called MultiViews. The MultiViews option allows a file to be called even if the extension is not loaded, so index would look for any files called index, regardless of their extension.

So the solution is to add:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

to the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

If you name a file `index` and put it in your root, does it 404, or load that file? I would try overriding the `DirectoryIndex` directive in your.htaccess file. The default there is usually index.html, but maybe yours is just index.

Comment: I'll do some testing, but either way, shouldn't the rewrite work (since the file doesn't exist)?